# Eigen3 colwise cross product with another matrix

Tags: eigen3

I'm trying to to write the following piece of code as one eigen expression:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,3,2> a, b, c(3,2);
a << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
b << 7,8,9,10,11,12;
for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
  c.col(i) = a.col(i).cross(b.col(i));
```

i.e. I would like to write something like

```
c = a.colwise().cross(b.colwise())
```

but this does not compile with Eigen 3.2.7. I've found that I can write

```
c = a.colwise().cross(b.col(0))
```

but this is not exactly what I want...

Your help would be very much appreciated. In my FEM code the number of columns of `a` and `b` is not 2 but in the order of 1e6 and efficiency is very important.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Raffael

Comment: You have some thing like `Matrix<double, 3, 1000000>`?!?! That is supposed to be allocated on the stack (slightly too big).

Comment: No, Sorry I forgot to mention that in my "real case" the matrices a,b,c are of type `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,Eigen::Dynamic>`.

Comment: This is still an issue right now. Could you share what you ended up doing?

Comment: I ended up calculating the cross product row-wise, that, e.g. `c.row(0) = a.row(2).cwiseProduct(b.row(3))-a.row(3).cwiseProduct(b.row(2))` and similarly for the other elements of `c`